# wordpress show time of post incorect into my plugin

Tags: wordpress

i create a widget thats show papular and recent post but thats show all of the time 2013 08 02 whats problem?
thats show correct with wp_query bu show more extra string i cant clear that.

```
function posts($sort = 'recent', $items = 3, $echo = TRUE, $bg_color = 'black')
```

{
    $return_html = '';

```
if($sort == 'recent')
{
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts='.$items.'&order=DESC&orderby=date&post_type=post&post_status=publish');
    $title = __('Recent Posts', THEMEDOMAIN);
}
else
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_content FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status= 'publish' ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0,".$items;
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $title = 'Popular Posts';
}

if(!empty($posts))
{

    $return_html.= '<h2 class="widgettitle">'.$title.'</h2>';
    $return_html.= '<ul class="posts blog '.$bg_color.'_wrapper">';

    $count_post = count($posts);

        foreach($posts as $post)
        {
            $image_thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'blog_thumb_image_url', true);
            $return_html.= '<li>';

            if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large'))
            {
                $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail', true);

                $return_html.= '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'"><img class="alignright frame" src="'.$image_url[0].'" alt="" /></a>';
            }

            $return_html.= '<strong class="title"><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></strong><br/><span class="post_attribute">'.get_the_time('F j, Y', $post->ID).'</span>';
            $return_html.= '</li>';

        }   

    $return_html.= '</ul>';
```

can anyone help me?
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Where is function `get_the_time` ?

Comment: see the end of question

Answer (score 0):

From [WP Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time),

> get_the_time returns the time of the current post for use in PHP. It
>   does not display the time. To display the time of a post, use
>   the_time(). This tag must be used within The Loop.

So I think you want to use, `the_time('F j, Y')`

---

Edit: Try adding this line as the first line in your `foreach` loop:

```
setup_postdata( $post );
```

Comment: I think you need to use [`The Loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) as stated in above quote.